# Issue integrating shopify store with 2checkout in case of non standard currency

Tags: paypal, shopify, 2checkout

I have a shopify store with default currency as PKR. I want to integrate 2checkout payment method for credit card transaction. But the problem is that 2checkout's standard currency is not PKR. Unless I change my store's default currency to USD integration does not work. Can there by a work around where the shopify checkout remains PKR but when the client selects credit card and proceeds to payment, the money is converted to USD and passed to 2checkout.

Answer (score 0):

This is not posible as Shopify checkout works with default store's currency. Why don't you try with another payment gateway like PayPal?